# Can I break my fast on the day of my exam due to diabetes?

Tags: halal-haram, sawm, medical

I suffer from type one diabetes and I am having exam in this week in uni. I am currently fasting and I have a problem: if I am not feeling quite well in exam, it would cost me a a lot. I was wondering if you give me an advice to make my decision: Can I break my fast on the day of the exam due to my poor health condition?

Comment: Before answering I need to know: Did your doctor allow you to fast? I mean on about any scholars website one reads that a chronicle illness such diabetes etc. is a reason for being allowed not to fast and feed for each missed day instead as we are not prohibited to harm ourselves as you can clearly read in the Quran http://legacy.quran.com/2/185 or http://legacy.quran.com/2/195 and in case one is financially not able to feed one could "wait" until he is able to do so. And in any special subject experts are the first people one should ask, and who knows your health better than your doctor?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can break the fast and can also compensate it as per Quran. Read the following verse:

"Fast for a specified number of days, but if any one among you is ill or on a journey, let him fast the same number of days later. For those who can fast only with extreme difficulty, there is a way to compensate -- the feeding of a needy person. But he who does good of his own accord shall be well rewarded; but to fast is better for you, if you only knew." Quran 2:184

Its between you and Allah. Decide from your own heart. Other people to whom you are asking may not understand you situation well.